# Where can I find evidence Windows USB boot devices are not supported?

Tags: windows, boot, usb-boot

I need written documentation, preferably from Microsoft, that installing Windows XP and newer to USB drives would not be possible, even when in a lab environment.

I am not trying to install from a USB drive. They want me to use USB drives as the primary boot device.

I've looked on Technet, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: I suppose there's "not possible", "not supported", and "not permitted under the EULA". Which is it that you're looking for? By the way, I don't have the answer to any of those. I'm just suggesting that clarification might be in order.

Answer (score 5):

Well, considering it is possible I seriously doubt you're going to find an article saying you can't.

http://www.informationweek.com/news/windows/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=177102101&pgno=1

http://www.ngine.de/index.jsp?pageid=4176

As a side note, Microsoft *used* to have an article that did say you couldn't do it.  But they pulled that because of mounting evidence to the contrary.

Comment: Do you know of any options for installing Vista/7 to a USB drive?

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to find a way to convince others that you "need" to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

It actually is possible with newer bios'.  I've created some boot sticks with UBCDWin that work like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

From the links it looks like you may get there with a lot of work and trial and error, and no support from Microsoft when you arrive. How about eSATA instead?